# How group values by keys of deep-level hashes?

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash, grouping

I'm trying to create a rake task, which which get data from model and generate a locale file like `en.yml`.

For example, input data:

```
[
   {a: {w: 0}, b: '2', c: '3'},
   {a: {q: 1}},
   {aa: {bb: {cc: '4'}}},
   {aa: {bb: {ee: '4'}}}
]
```

Output data should looks like:

```
    {
      a: {w: 0, q: 1},
      b: '2',
      c: '3',
      aa: {bb: {cc: '4', ee: '4'} }}
    }
```

So values of the same keys on the same deep level should be grouped..
How can I do it using ruby's array and hash methods?

Comment: what should happen if there is a conflict (same key at same level has 2 different values) ? For instance you have 
   {aa: {bb: {cc: '4'}}},
   {aa: {bb: {cc: '12'}}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails Active Support Core extension, [`Hash#deep_merge`](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#merging) accomplishes the same.  You could make use of that gem instead of re-inventing the wheel.

```
require "active_support/core_ext/hash"
arr = [
   {a: {w: 0}, b: '2', c: '3'},
   {a: {q: 1}},
   {aa: {bb: {cc: '4'}}},
   {aa: {bb: {ee: '4'}}}
]

p arr.reduce {|h1, h2| h1.deep_merge(h2)}
#=> {:a=>{:w=>0, :q=>1}, :b=>"2", :c=>"3", :aa=>{:bb=>{:cc=>"4", :ee=>"4"}}}
```

---

If you dont' want to use the gem, you can copy the code of `deep_merge` from [Rails code base here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/deep_merge.rb).

Answer (score 1):

You can use recursive method for nasted hash structure.

```
require 'yaml'

def group_by_keys(sub_hash, export)
  sub_hash.each do |k, v|
    if Hash === v
      export[k] ||= {}
      self.send(__method__, v, export[k])
    else
      export[k] = v
    end
  end
end

yaml = "[
   {a: {w: 0}, b: '2', c: '3'},
   {a: {q: 1}},
   {aa: {bb: {cc: '4'}}},
   {aa: {bb: {ee: '4'}}}
]"

imput = YAML.load(yaml)

export = imput.each_with_object({}){|sub_hash, exp| group_by_keys(sub_hash, exp)}
```

**export**

```
p export

# {
#   "a" => {"w" => 0, "q" => 1},
#   "b" => "2",
#   "c" => "3",
#   "aa" => {
#     "bb" => {"cc" => "4", "ee" => "4"}
#   }
# }
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Well done. I hadn't seen `send(__method__, ...)` before. Is that just to permit you to change the method name without having to remember to change it in the body of the method as well? (I assume you know you don't need `self.`.)

Answer (score 0):

```
# No gems needed, to scale however you'll need to add code
hash_array = [{a: {w: 0}, b: "2", c: "3"}, {a: {q: 1}}, {aa: {bb: {cc:"4"}}}, {aa: {bb: {ee: "4" }}}]

new_hash = {}
test_array = []
hash_array.each do |hashes|
  if test_array.include?(hashes.keys[0])
    if hashes.values[0].values[0].class == Hash
      merge_this = hashes.values[0].values[0]
      new_hash[hashes.keys[0]].values[0].merge!(merge_this)
    else
      new_hash[hashes.keys[0]].merge!(hashes.values[0])
    end
  else
    new_hash.merge!(hashes)
  end
  test_array << hashes.keys[0]
end
# You can easily move braces into standard .yml format
p new_hash # returns {:a=>{:w=>0, :q=>1}, :b=>"2", :c=>"3", :aa=>{:bb=>{:cc=>"4", :ee=>"4"}}}
```